# Date format conversion in Javasscript

Tags: javascript, date-conversion

In javascript, how to bring the date from the format (dd-mm-yy) and display it on the page as (dd-mm-yyyy)?
Ex: 10-Mar-15 to 10-Mar-2015

Comment: Use the standard [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the complete date -
new Date(Date.parse("01-Jan-09"));

This will show date-month-year

var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var a = new Date(Date.parse("07-jul-89"));

alert(a.getDate()+"-"+monthNames[a.getMonth()]+"-"+a.getFullYear());

output -
7-july-1989